# Matlab - updating objects on a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, timer, simulation, figure

I am trying to add a timer a simulation i am working on. At the moment i can get the timer to display in the location i want, however i cant make the numbers clear each other, i.e they all just stack on top of each other slowly creating a solid black mess. I have tried implementing a clf function but it just clears the entire figure. The code for the timer is:

```
HH = 0; MM = 0; SS = 0;
timer = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);
text(-450,450,timer);  %% adjust location of clock in graph using the first two arguments: (x,y) coordinates

for t = 1:86400  

    SS = SS + 1;
    if SS == 60
        MM = MM + 1;
        SS = 0;
    end
    if MM == 60
        HH = HH + 1;
        MM = 0;
    end
    timer = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);  %% construct time string after all adjustments to HH, MM, SS
    clf(f,'reset');  %% clear previous clock display
    text(-450,450,timer);   %% re-plot time to figure  

    if t == EventTimes(1)
        uav1 = uav1.uavSetDestin([event1(2:3) 0]);
        plot(event1(2),event1(3),'+')
        hold on
    end  
    if t == EventTimes(2)
        uav2 = uav2.uavSetDestin([event2(2:3) 0]);
        plot(event2(2),event2(3),'r+')
        hold on
    end
```

Is there a way i can reset only the timer function so it displays properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store the [handle to the text object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#outputarg_t) and update the [`String`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#property_string) property of this existing object rather than creating a new `text` object every time.

```
%// The first time through your loop
htext = text(-450, 450, timer);

%// Every other time through the loop
set(htext, 'String', sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS)
```

You will also want to do something similar with the `plot` objects rather than clearing the figure and redrawing all of the plots every iteration.

Integrating this with your code we get something like:

```
%// Create the initial text object
HH = 0; MM = 0; SS = 0;
timerString = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);
htext = text(-450, 450, timeString); 

%// Create the plot objects
hplot1 = plot(NaN, NaN, '+');
hplot2 = plot(NaN, NaN, 'r+');

for t = 1:86400 
    SS = SS + 1;

    %// I could help myself and made this significantly shorter
    MM = MM + (mod(SS, 60) == 0);
    HH = HH + (mod(MM, 60) == 0);

    %// Update the timer string
    timerString = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);
    set(htext, 'String', timerString);

    %// Update your plots depending upon which EventTimes() 
    if t == EventTimes(1)
        uav1 = uav1.uavSetDestin([event1(2:3) 0]);
        set(hplot1, 'XData', event1(2), 'YData', event1(3));
    elseif t == EventTimes(2)
        uav2 = uav2.uavSetDestin([event2(2:3) 0]);
        set(hplot2, 'XData', event2(2), 'YData', event2(3));
    end

    %// Force a redraw event
    drawnow;
end
```

Comment: Damn @Suever you're fast