# working with timer object to refresh an axes on a GUI

Tags: matlab

I am dealing with timer object in the MATLAB GUI. Assume that we have two axes on a GUI and under display update function we plot on each axes separately. The problem here is that when the plot function executes the hObject properties changes like this: before plot execution:

```
get(hObject,'Children')
ans =

3x1 graphics array:
UIControl    (startbutton)
Axes         (axes1)
Axes         (axes2)
```

After plot execution axes1 disappears.

```
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',1,'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','b','LineStyle','none')
K>> get(hObject,'Children')
ans =

3x1 graphics array:
UIControl    (startbutton)
Axes
Axes         (axes2)
```

Main part of my code is as follows:

```
function test3_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;

handles.timer = timer(...
    'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...       % Run timer repeatedly
    'Period', 3, ...                        % Initial period is 1 sec.
    'TimerFcn', {@update_display, hObject}); % Specify callback function

guidata(hObject,handles);
function startbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if strcmp(get(handles.timer, 'Running'), 'off')
    start(handles.timer);
end
function update_display(obj,event,hObject)
handles = guidata(hObject);
guidata(hObject, handles);
axes(handles.axes2)
cla(handles.axes2
mapshow(x,y,'LineWidth',1,'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','b') 
axes(handles.axes1)
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',1,'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','b','LineStyle','none')
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

So when the timer gets to the refreshing time (and the execution of display update function), a new figure is ploted and each period only that plot updates not the axes1 on the GUI. Do you have any idea and how can I solve this isuue?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll need to post more code to actually help you out. That being said you should store the `plot` object and update it rather than continuously calling `plot` to create a new plot.

Comment: You are right @Suever, So you are telling that using `plot`, `mapshow`, `surf` and other plotting functions in the display_update function should be avoided because it changes the hObject in this way. I think I should use `set` instead but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: See examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37299989/670206) and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html

Comment: @Suever I have added more information of my code. I am totally confused how to deal with this problem. please help me if you have any suggestions or comments. Thanks